# Terraform: Import resource which is held in a module, not root

Tags: terraform

I have an existing resource which i'd like to import into my config, to keep with style I have written this into a module, as below.

When I try to import it (using `terraform import resource.module id`) I get an error, as below
`>Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module.`

If I add this to my root, it errors on a dupe resource.

How do I go about importing a resource which is not in my root module?

Current structure:
#modules.tf

```
module my_module {
   source ./modules
   ...
}
```

#./modules/main.tf

```
resource 'my_resource' 'my_resource_name' {
   ...
}
```

#./modules/output.tf

```
output {
   value = ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to import resources into terraform is to first run `terraform plan`, check the command output and see what's the *resource names it generates under the module*.

Then run `terraform import <resource-name-in-module> <arn/id, depend on the resource>`.

So in your case, you would probably need to run something like

```
terraform import 'my_module.my_resource.my_resource_name' 'id'
```

Note the quotes around the module name; if the module contains `count`, this is necessary so it's a good habit to get used to.

Comment: Thanks for this.
My actual problem (which I don't think was well reprex'd here) required a `moved` block as well. The import was very helpful, however, thnak you.